# Issue parsing OData filter string

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using OData to query and filter a result set that has a `Priority` of Low or Medium. After reading the OData documentation I am pretty sure I am doing this correctly with the following GET request:

`https://localhost:5001/api/v1/BusinessProcesses/ProcessWithResults?$filter=Priority%20IN%20(%27Low%27,%20%27Medium%27)`

Which in my Angular code looks like:

```
`${this.rootUrl}BusinessProcesses/ProcessWithResults?$filter=priority IN ('Low', 'Medium')`;
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to perform operation 'IN'
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'member')
```

The funny thing is that I do not even see where my Web API GET endpoint references a `member` property or object.

The error is occuring in the method below when attempting to parse the filter on the line `Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateExpression = language.Parse<T>(filter);`:

```
public void Parse(string queryString)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryString))
            {
                var queryStrings = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
                if (queryStrings.HasKeys() && queryStrings.AllKeys.Contains("$filter"))
                {
                    string filter = queryStrings["$filter"];
                    var language = new ODataFilterLanguage();
                    Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicateExpression = language.Parse<T>(filter);
                    Filter = predicateExpression.Compile();
                }
                if (queryStrings.HasKeys() && queryStrings.AllKeys.Contains("$top"))
                {
                    string top = queryStrings["$top"];
                    ParseTop(top);
                }
                if (queryStrings.HasKeys() && queryStrings.AllKeys.Contains("$skip"))
                {
                    string skip = queryStrings["$skip"];
                    ParseSkip(skip);
                }

                if (queryStrings.HasKeys() && queryStrings.AllKeys.Contains("$orderby"))
                {
                    string orderby = queryStrings["$orderby"];
                    OrderByClause<T> orderbyClause = new OrderByClause<T>();
                    orderbyClause.Parse(orderby);
                    Sort = orderbyClause.RootExpression;
                    SortDirection = orderbyClause.Direction;
                }
            }
        }
```

I am very new to OData and am not sure what the issue is. Can anyone help me troubleshoot the issue? I have not been able to find anything that comes close to my issue. The only thing I can say is that I have a working example that looks like this:

```
https://localhost:5001/api/v1/BusinessProcesses/ProcessWithResults?$filter=status%20eq%20%27%27%20or%20status%20eq%20%27%27%20or%20status%20eq%20%27%27%20or%20status%20eq%20%27%27%20or%20priority%20eq%20%27Low%27%20or%20priority%20eq%20%27Medium%27%20or%20priority%20eq%20%27%27%20or%20ownerName%20eq%20%27%27
```

In Angular code it looks like:

```
this.rootUrl + `BusinessProcesses/ProcessWithResults?$filter=status eq '${obj.status[0] != undefined ? obj.status[0].name : ''}' or status eq '${obj.status[1] != undefined ? obj.status[1].name : ''}' or status eq '${obj.status[2] != undefined ? obj.status[2].name : ''}' or status eq '${obj.status[3] != undefined ? obj.status[3].name : ''}'`;
    url += ` or priority eq '${obj.priority[0] != undefined ? obj.priority[0].name : ''}' or priority eq '${obj.priority[1] != undefined ? obj.priority[1].name : ''}' or priority eq '${obj.priority[2] != undefined ? obj.priority[2].name : ''}' or ownerName eq ${ownerFilterUrl}`;
```

Comment: After further analyzing the point of failure I described above, I see that we are using the StringToExpression library for parsing our OData filter strings and that is where ODataFilterLanguage.Parse method exists. Since this is where it is failing can someone tell me why my query (the way it is structured) is not able to be parsed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN may not be supported in the OData library you are using.

Don't see it mentioned as a filter in [ASP.NET WEB API 2 reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options).
It was added in OData v4.0.1 according to docs.

Alternative would be:

```
$filter=(priority eq 'Low') or (priority eq 'Medium')
```

Comment: After further analyzing the point of failure I described above, I see that we are using the StringToExpression library for parsing our OData filter strings and that is where `ODataFilterLanguage.Parse` method exists. Since this is where it is failing can someone tell me why my query (the way it is structured) is not able to be parsed?

Comment: Also, would this be a valid filter:

Comment: `$filter=((priority eq 'Low') or (priority eq 'Medium') or (priority eq 'High')) and (owner eq 'Dean')`

Comment: Yes that would work, put this on a browser to see same structure: http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People?$filter=((FirstName eq 'Vincent') or (FirstName eq 'Scott')) and (FirstName eq 'Scott')

Comment: But services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/People?$filter=FirstName in ('Vincent')   gives syntax error at position 12 (where the ‘in’ is. So it seems like odata is not recognising 'in' statement. Does the alternative in my answer work from your app?

Comment: Thank you. I ended up doing what you said but it ended up having to look like this:

Comment: let url = this.rootUrl + `ProcessWithResults?$filter=(status eq '${obj.status[0] != undefined ? obj.status[0].name : ''}') or (status eq '${obj.status[1] != undefined ? obj.status[1].name : ''}') or (status eq '${obj.status[2] != undefined ? obj.status[2].name : ''}') or (status eq '${obj.status[3] != undefined ? obj.status[3].name : ''}'))`;
    url += ` and ((priority eq '${obj.priority[0] != undefined ? obj.priority[0].name : ''}')  or (priority eq '${obj.priority[2] != undefined ? obj.priority[2].name : ''}')) and (ownerName eq ${ownerFilterUrl})`;

Comment: Wow, indeed it is.

Comment: Yes, there has to be a better way. Problem is I need to move fast on this.

Comment: May have to just just go old school and create a POCO which can have the filter criteria - FilterCriteria . In this add properties “Field string” and “Values list<guid>”. Angular can pass this to controller and I can add this capability to my EntityController as well as EntityRepository classes. Then it is available for all my derived controller and repository classes.  (Essentially it means do it as if no OData exists)